# What joint combination gives you an 6 DoF workspace?

Tags: robot, design, joints

If you want to have a 6 DoF workspace of your end-effector you need 6 joints.
But how exactly do the joints have to be ordered?

For instance:

1. A robot with 6 revolute joints where all the rotation axes are parallel gives you a 3 DoF workspace (two translation, one rotation).
2. A robot with 6 revolute joints where five joints have parallel rotation axes (e.g. roll-yaw-yaw-yaw-yaw-yaw or yaw-roll-yaw-yaw-yaw-yaw) gives you a 4 DoF workspace (three translation, one rotation)
3. A robot with 6 prismatic joints gives you a 3 DoF workspace (three translation, 0 rotation).
4. A robot with 5 prismatic joints and 1 rotational joint gives you a 4 DoF workspace (three translation, 1 rotation).

For more complex setups like altering rotation axes (yaw-pitch-yaw-pitch-yaw-pitch) it is difficult to use your intuition to determine how many DoF the end-effector has in the achievable workspace. Same holds true for a combination of prismatic and revolute joints.

Can you help?

Kind regards from Berlin